# Role of tol argument in QR decomposition

Tags: r

I am new user in R. Could you please tell me or introduce some refrences which describe the `tol` argument in calculating a QR decomposition in R?

For example what is the difference of this two lines:

```
qr(A, tol=1e-07) #Doesn't work

qr(A, tol=1e-20) #Works
```

Why do I get my desired resullt with such a small value of `tol`, but not with the bigger value?

Comment: have you looked at the documentation on `qr()`?

Comment: Yes, but I did not underestand it. That's why I ask question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `tol` argument controls whether `qr` will return a value or not for a column  depending on whether the column has been judged to be linearly dependent. I would think that reducing the `tol` value below 1e-16 would be defeating the purpose of that check. (That's pretty much the pragmatic  definition of zero in double precision math.)

First look at `qr.default` and then find the FORTRAN code:

http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/appl/dqrdc2.f

This is the comment from the FORTRAN routine that describes the logic:

```
c     cycle the columns from l to p left-to-right until one
c     with non-negligible norm is located.  a column is considered
c     to have become negligible if its norm has fallen below
c     tol times its original norm.  the check for l .le. k
c     avoids infinite cycling.
```